# Write the event of drawn cards

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

From a deck of $52$ cards, take out $26$ cards. The event $A_{ij}$ means that there are at least $i$ clubs and at least $j$ spades. I need to write the event using set-theoretic operations and $A_{ij}$ that all of these $26$ cards are red.

My answer is:
$$A_{00} \setminus (A_{01} \cup A_{10})$$
Am I right?

Comment: That’s correct! Note that $A_{00}$ is of course the set of all outcomes, so you can also use a set complement.